# Cannot get react-chartjs to update

Tags: javascript, chart.js, reactjs

I am trying to follow the "Example usage" code from [react-chartjs github page](https://github.com/jhudson8/react-chartjs)

I am new to javascript and react and probably just being naive. How can I get the new chartData from "_onChange" to update my PolarAreaChart? I tried something more direct by calling element.getDocumentById("polarChart"), but that returns nothing and then I cannot call .update on it... the whole "insert redraw in the xml" and it will magically call update seems magical to me :(

PolarPlot.jsx

```
var React = require ('react');
var PolarAreaChart = require ('react-chartjs').PolarArea;
var FilterStore = require ('FilterStore')

var PolarPlot = React.createClass ({
  componentWillMount: function () {
      FilterStore.addChangeListener  (this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange: function () {
    console.log("time to update")

    chartData = [
        {
            value: 300,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
        }]
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <PolarAreaChart id="polarChart" data={chartData} options={chartOptions} redraw/>
    );
  }
});

var chartData = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    },
    {
        value: 40,
        color: "#949FB1",
        highlight: "#A8B3C5",
        label: "Grey"
    },
    {
        value: 120,
        color: "#4D5360",
        highlight: "#616774",
        label: "Dark Grey"
    }

];

var chartOptions = [
  {
      //Boolean - Show a backdrop to the scale label
      scaleShowLabelBackdrop : true,

      //String - The colour of the label backdrop
      scaleBackdropColor : "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",

      // Boolean - Whether the scale should begin at zero
      scaleBeginAtZero : true,

      //Number - The backdrop padding above & below the label in pixels
      scaleBackdropPaddingY : 2,

      //Number - The backdrop padding to the side of the label in pixels
      scaleBackdropPaddingX : 2,

      //Boolean - Show line for each value in the scale
      scaleShowLine : true,

      //Boolean - Stroke a line around each segment in the chart
      segmentShowStroke : true,

      //String - The colour of the stroke on each segement.
      segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",

      //Number - The width of the stroke value in pixels
      segmentStrokeWidth : 2,

      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps : 100,

      //String - Animation easing effect.
      animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",

      //Boolean - Whether to animate the rotation of the chart
      animateRotate : true,

      //Boolean - Whether to animate scaling the chart from the centre
      animateScale : false,

      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

  }

];

module.exports = PolarPlot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PolarPlot` component is not rendered unless you explicitly change the state. Your `chartData` is not part of the component state. So assigning a new array to that variable does nothing more than that. *Move* this `chartData` to the component state. Then, whenever you update this state variable you are going to force the re-render. Something like this:

```
var PolarPlot = React.createClass ({
  componentWillMount: function () {
      FilterStore.addChangeListener  (this._onChange);
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {chartData: chartData};
  },

  _onChange: function () {
    console.log("time to update")
    this.setState({
      chartData: [{
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
      }]
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <PolarAreaChart id="polarChart" data={this.state.chartData} options={chartOptions} redraw/>
    );
  }
});
```

If you want to know more about how components rendering reacts to state changes check [Reactive state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state) section from the React Tutorial.